# Initializing array of objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, array-initialization

I need help in understanding how to initialize an object of a class in Java.

My code was something like this:

```
...
Test t[] = null;
...
for (i=0;i<20;i++)
   t[i] = new Test(10,20);
...
```

When I write the above code in Eclipse, it gives me an error saying that "Null Pointer Access: The variable data can only be null at this location".

I tried all ways of correcting the error, but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allocate space for the array itself, *then* initialize them elements.

```
Test[] t = new Test[20];
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    t[i] = new Test(10, 20);
}
```

If the array's length is variable, you can just pass the value like you would any other variable.

```
int arraySize = 35;
Test[] t = new Test[arraySize];
for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    t[i] = new Test(10, 20);
}
```

Array size is fixed once you initialize it, but you can always get the array's length using the `arr.length` property.

Comment: What if, i don't know how much space it will occupy? Actually that space is determined during runtime

Comment: @Anshuman Take a look at my answer, and also the Java `ArrayList` class.

Comment: @Alexis: Thank you. I have done that way. I was asking, if there was a different way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your array by specifying its size.

`Test[] t = new Test[20];`

If you do not want to limit the array size. You may consider to use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically.

`List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<Test>();`

Answer (score 2):

In Java an object array is **immutable** and must be initialized.

There are few things to do.

You can either provide the elements during the assignment:

```
Test t[] = { new Test(10, 20), new Test(30, 40) };
```

If you do not know the values, you can assign the array with proper allocation:

```
Test t[] = new Test[4];
```

In your situation you still need to initialize the array.

Generally speaking, this is not required at declaration, unless the variable is final.

```
Test t[];            // declaration

t[] = new Test[20];  // assignment

for ( i=0 ; i<20 ; i++ ) {

    t[i] = new Test(10,20);

}
```

Java also has a group of classes that work with lists, arrays, key-value sets, and linked-lists.

If you need to use a **mutable** array, use the `ArrayList` object.

This will allow you to avoid the initialization.

Here is a brief example:

```
ArrayList<Test> t = new ArrayList<Test>();

for( i=0 ; i<20 ; i++ ) {

    t.add(new Test(10,20));

}
```

Mutable lists are expensive in comparison to immutable object arrays, but the Java coders have really tweaked the `ArrayList` class, using the `System.arraycopy()` function.

So you will not see much of a performance degrade.

Simply put, only use a mutable ArrayList when you have absolutely no way of knowing your required allocation space.

Answer (score 1):

Need to **initialize your array test[]** like below and then use it

```
Test[] t = new Test[20];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Test[] t = new Test[20];
```

When you set t to null it tries to access an array that isn't there.

Answer (score -1):

In java, datatypes can be primitive or reference. Reference types are either Class or Interface type or Array type.
When you want to create an Array of objects, first you need to declare and instantiate the array Object itself and then instantiate the required objects of the class and assign them to the array object.

```
 ArrayDataType[] ArrayName=new ArrayDataType[Dimensions];
    for(int i=0;i<Dimensions;i++){
    Arrayname[i]=new ObjectDataType();  
    \\ where the ObjectDatatype can be either ArrayDataType or SubType
    }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Hi August, I haphazardly submitted the answer before, was modifying it , did it now, hope it helps